# Using Repeater Control as a command parameter for a nested gridview

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0

I have a repeater which contains a nested gridview. Now I need to be able to retrieve a value databound in a label inside of a repeater and use it as an input parameter for the gridview.

Here is some code which will hopefully give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
enter code here

  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="RepeaterDS"  OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_SendRollNumber">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table style="width: 615px;" id="Table1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>Roll #:</b>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="RollIDLabel" Text='<%# Eval("RollID") %>' />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="RollIDLabelCode" Text='<%# Eval("RollID") %>' Visible="false" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>Address:</b>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="AddressLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>' />
                    </table>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><b>Parties:</b></asp:Label>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE"
                        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical"
                        AllowPaging="True" Width="620px" DataSourceID="AssessmentDetailsFromRollIDDS"
                        EmptyDataText="None Associated" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true">
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Property Assessment" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                                FooterStyle-BackColor="White">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="PropAssessType" runat="server" Width="90%" Text='<%# Eval("PropertyAssessmentType") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="PropAssessDsc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PropertyAssessmentDesc") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3E4E4E" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="RepeaterDS" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
        SelectMethod="GetRollNumberbyAppealID" TypeName="BusinessLayer.BSO.Roll_AssessmentDetailsBSO">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="AppealID" QueryStringField="appealID" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="AssessmentDetailsFromRollIDDS" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
        SelectMethod="GetAssessDetailsFromRollID" OnSelecting="AssessmentDetailsFromRollIDDS_Selecting" TypeName="BusinessLayer.BSO.Assessment_DetailsBSO">
        <SelectParameters>
           <asp:ControlParameter Name="RollID" ControlID="RollIDLabelCode" Type="String" /> 
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I've tried to cut out as much code as possible while leaving the guts of the problem in.  So I basically want the label control RollIDLabelCode which is located in a repeater to also be an input into my gridview. The problem is that I keep getting errors such as can't find the control RollIDLabelCode.  I've heard there is a bug in which you need to specify all naming containers. which I've tried with no luck.

Another route I've tried is doing this in the code behind.

```
enter code here


    public void Repeater1_OnItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
                  // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            string  test = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("RollIDLabel")).Text;
        }
    }

    public void AssessmentDetailsFromRollIDDS_OnSelecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

        e.InputParameters["RollID"] = "Need the Info here";
    }
```

These functions are called on the repeater being databound and the objectdatasource onselecting function. And these work separately very well. I just need to know how to get the information from the string test in the Repeater1_OnItemDataBound function to the e.InputParameters["RollID"] in the OnSelecting function.

Hopefully someone knows how to do this.  I am new to .net programming. I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The RollIDLabelCode label is set visible=false which means it will not exist when rendered so trying to access the value won't be possible.  You'll need to use a different control that is hidden but exists when rendered.  For instance a GridView has a datakeys that exist within the control but are not rendered.  It is used to retrieve a key value for the row to retreive more data, for example.

Comment: This is unfortunately not my problem. I can set it to visible and still have errors. If I take the label out of the repeater the page will at least load. But with it linked inside of the repeater I get the following error. 

Could not find control 'RollIDLabelCode' in ControlParameter 'RollID'.